# How to store data with lots of subdata but keep easy and simple access in python

Tags: python, text

Making an open world choose-your-own-adventure text based game in python. Sorta new to python so I'm not sure what the best way to do this is. I want to store information about lots of different items such as armor, weapons, etc. I also want to store information about different towns and the NPCs in them. How can I store this info, all with their own subdata such as a swords damage, in a easy to use, sorted manner?

My first thought was to use classes. This was so I could do something like

```
class goblin:
    health = 10

class items:
    class weapons:
        class ironSword:
            damage = 1
            
goblin.health -= items.weapons.ironSword
```

But i figured this wouldn't work because I need the items to be accessible, like a variable. This is because I am using a class for the player, which has a list for their inventory. I want to be able to store these items in said list, Which I am not sure how to do with classes.

Comment: The most convenient way to store your data would be to use a database e.g., MySql. I also recommend [Getting started](https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach of organizing the data in classes is good. But you're defining the classes in a rather complex way. A better option would be to use `inheritence`. If you are unfamiliar with the concepts of `inheritence` or `subclasses`, you can check out this excellent video by [Corey Schafer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RSl87lqOXDE).

You may want to do something like this:

```py
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, description):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description

class Weapon(Item):
    def __init__(self, name, description, damage):
        super().__init__(name, description)
        self.damage = damage

class Armor(Item):
    def __init__(self, name, description, defense):
        super().__init__(name, description)
        self.defense = defense
```

Then you can create as many `objects` (your items) you want from these classes like this:

```py
iron_sword = Weapon("Iron Sword", "A basic iron sword.", damage=10)
machine_gun = Weapon("Machine Gun", "An automatic assault rifle.", damage=90)
leather_armor = Armor("Leather Armor", "Light armor made of leather.", defense=5)
```